# Android Views using Templates

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, templates

I've got multiple screens in my applications, which are nearly the same: 
Basically there's a heading on the top and a view at the bottom including buttons. If I click on a button, the text of the heading should change. Then, when clicked on determined buttons, there should appear a second header, under the first one, in some cases a third. Each of them includes buttons. When clicking on a button of the second header, the third header should change, when clicking on the third header, only the content below the headers should change.

My target is also to nest (3) different templates, but to define each of them only for once (in xml). Is there a way to do this?

[image: picture]

Don't know, if the image works, here's the [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/v58r4eson2xhior/2013-11-01%2018.32.18.jpg) to dropbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[One solution](http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2009/02/android-layout-tricks-2-reusing-layouts.html) is to declare different xml Views, which could be included by using the 'include' tag in other xml files.

Answer (score 1):

Your main layout should be 3rd template layout.
You just have to hide the buttons or the button layout using attribute `setvisibility="gone"` in xml layout and in java when you click the button you can set visiblity to visible and you can also do set text to textview to change the header text to whatever you want on click of the buttons.
Hope this helps you